# Shebang conflict with doxygen

Tags: python, doxygen, shebang

Does doxygen doesn't work properly on python script with a shebang?

I tried one python script with shebang to my company's tool directory and ran doxygen.
It was not able to display namespace (functions) at all.

Please share if you guys faced similar experience.

Comment: This kinda thing is easier to debug if you provide all the relevant details.  The problem would probably reveal itself if you showed the script and the output from an `strace` run.

Comment: @brian I am sorry for bring unclear with my query. 
However i have found a solution for the same: Set EXTRACT_ALL in config to YES and it will run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enable EXTRACT_ALL to YES in the config file, doxygen will generate proper desired results.

But the question still remains, why doxygen failed to generate documentation file for python with EXTRACT_ALL = NO.
Anyone with better answer can help me here.

Answer (score 0):

that sounds to me like a scripting problem and not like a conflict between Shebang and doxygen

Comment: Doxygen doesn't parse python syntax, but just the comments.
Incidentally, when i enabled EXTRACT_ALL to YES,doxygen was able to read it and desired results were generated.

But the question still remains, why doxygen failed to generate documentation file for python with EXTRACT_ALL = NO