# How to make doxygen ignore the first line of a Python script?

Tags: python, doxygen

I have a docstring in the beginning of a Python script that Doxygen parses perfectly. However, if I add `#!/usr/bin/env python` in the beginning of the file (to make the script executable), the entire docstring is not recognized by Doxygen.

So, how can I make Doxygen ignore this first line?

Example of a working docstring:

```
"""@package HelloWorld
This is a docstring and it's recognized by doxygen."""
```

Example of a non-working docstring:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""@package HelloWorld
This is a docstring and it's not recognized by doxygen because of the first line."""
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shebang conflict with doxygen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890199/shebang-conflict-with-doxygen)

Comment: This is a more specific question than that one I think, even though they are related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found it: I need to use a parser first. I tried [doxypy](http://code.foosel.org/doxypy) and it works really well. You only have to make the following changes in your doxy_conf file:

```
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES = YES
INPUT_FILTER = "python path/to/doxypy.py"
```